How do I calculate a mediation model with 2 independent variables, 1 mediator and 2 outcome variables with R?
It is suggested that both independent variables could influence the mediator, which in turn could have an effect on both outcome variables (direct effects are also expected).
All variables are on intervall scale level with likert scale. Sample size is 180.
How can I calculate that in R? I'm new to R and don't know if and how R can do this.
Can I somehow use SEM for this? If so how?
I would prefer to calculate everything in a single model instead of calculating 4 different mediation models. Is that possible? Both independent variables are somewhat related (one is a positive experience at work and one a negative experience, but still don't belong to the same construct), and the two dependent variables are not related to each other.
It's a cross-sectional study. (That's why I'm interested in correlations because I can't speak of causal effects).
Any help is very appreciated, thanks a lot!
Model picture here:

